# What is the experimental evidence - direct or indirect - for Hawking or Unruh radiation?

Tags: estimation, hawking-radiation, unruh-effect

I'm wondering what evidence exists, direct or indirect, for Hawking or Unruh radiation.

I believe one of the initial goals for the [Fermi LAT mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_Gamma-ray_Space_Telescope) was to look for evaporating microscopic black holes, which would be direct observation of Hawking radiation, but that this has not been observed by that mission - is that correct?

For the indirect evidence, I'm wondering if there is anything analogous to how the [Hulse-Taylor binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulse%E2%80%93Taylor_binary) was indirect evidence for gravity waves - is there some analogous measured effect of energy loss or change in other physical property that we attribute to Hawking/Unruh radiation?

I'm aware of a similar question "[Is Hawking radiation a theory or a hypothesis?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/151047/is-hawking-radiation-a-theory-or-a-hypothesis/151074#151074)" but that question could be construed as more concerned with the semantics of the words theory and hypothesis, so I created this new question.

Comment: Even indirect evidence of Hawking radiation is tricky, unless it's coming from tiny primordial black holes. According to https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator the radiation of a 3 solar mass BH is only $10^{-29}$ watts, at a temperature of 20 nanokelvins; it absorbs far more energy from stray atoms and the CMB.

Comment: Essentially a dupe of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/699164/25301 and/or  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/367147/25301

Comment: None of those questions addressed the Fermi LAT mission

Answer (score 3):

As of 2023 there is no experimental evidence of Hawking or Unruh radiation.